# Unix Mail Content printed in a single row

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a file which contains the following listing

Listing.txt

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
File4.txt
File5.txt
```

I have a shell script which uses the file as body on my email.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh

recipients=/recipients.txt
listing=/listing.txt
email_content=/email.txt

echo `cat $listing` > $email_content

mail -s "File Listing" `cat $recipients` < $email_content
```

However, when I get the mail the contents appear to like this. They were printed in a single row.

```
File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt File4.txt File5.txt
```

How can I have the listing similar to how it was listed in Listing.txt where it's line by line?

Comment: Use  simply `cat $listing > $email_content` instead of `echo \`cat $listing\` > $email_content`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this once:

```
mail -s "File Listing" `cat $recipients` < echo "`cat ${email_content}`"
```

Comment: Can someone help me with the formatting of the above statement. The backticks seems to have disappeared and will cause syntax errors.

Comment: Add "\" to escape backticks within backticks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with

```
echo `cat $listing` > $email_content
```

THe arguments to echo are interpreted, and the newlines get lost.
You can fix this with quotes

```
echo "`cat $listing`" > $email_content
```

You can make the solution shorter (as given by @KaushikNayak) with

```
cat $listing > $email_content
# or
cp $listing > $email_content
# or
mail -s "File Listing" `cat $recipients` < $listing
```

Try to avoid backtics and use more quotes and curly braces:

```
mail -s "File Listing" $(cat "${recipients}") < "${listing}"
```